# How can I add frameworks in Xcode 4?

Tags: qt, xcode4.2

I am building my Qt project in Xcode 4.2, using an external build system project (building with 'make'). I have the build system ready and I can build applications, but I can't import Qt code from the code editor. So how do I link against the QtGui.framework and the QtCore.framework in Xcode 4.2 using 'External build system' project settings?

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [qmake](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-platform-notes.html).

From the `pro` file you can create a xcode project.

`Developers on Mac OS X can take advantage of qmake's support for Xcode project files, as described in Qt is Mac OS X Native, by running qmake to generate an Xcode project from an existing qmake project files. For example:
 qmake -spec macx-xcode project.pro`

Spend some time in understanding qmake, it will help you a lot.

Comment: I've already tried that.. the problem is that qmake is not compatible with Xcode 4, and so all projects generated by qmake will crash Xcode 4.2.